# SSL certificate issues when communicating with Ably

Tags: ssl-certificate, real-time, ably-realtime

I'm on a Windows system and when I try connecting to Ably, I'm getting the following errors(s):

```
  cURL error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by out of date root certificates on your server or local machine.  In order to fix this problem, follow the instructions from one of the related issues:

[PHP SSL certificate problem](https://github.com/ably/ably-php/issues/32)

[Ruby certificate verify failed](https://github.com/ably/ably-ruby/issues/87)